# what transport is singalr currently using at runtime?

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I want to know what transport does singalr has currently selected, and is there any event fired when signalr changes its transport in client side not in server side logic.

i know there is a solution by reading the query-string from server side to know what it's current transport,but i want to catch this on client.

something like

```
var signalRhubs = $.hubConnection();
signalRhubs.transportChange(function(transport){

});
```

please help me with the issue.

Comment: try `$.connection.hub.transport.name`

Comment: @Pawel ,its not working